# Using numeric integration to find the area enclosed by loop of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, area, numerical-integration

I am trying to find or write some code that can give me the area between two lines, and if the lower one crosses the higher one an negative area is accounted for. For this (cannot post an image :( ) . I have writen code but am not 100% confident with the answers. I have also tried to just using a numpy function of np.trapz.

```
def TrapzCn(n):

Uy = Upper(n)
Ly = Lower(n)
xc = Open(L[0])
Top = np.trapz(Uy,x=xc[:10])
Bottom = np.trapz(Ly,x=xc[:10])
return(Top + Bottom)
```

and here's mine

```
def Cn(n):

Uy = Upper(n)
xc = Open(L[0])
Ly = Lower(n)
for i in range(len(Ly)):
  Ly[i] = float(Ly[i])
  Uy[i] = float(Uy[i])
A = 0
i = 0
while i+1 < len(Uy):
    A1 = (xc[i+1] - xc[i]) * ((Uy[i] + Uy[i+1])/2)
    A2 = (xc[i+1] - xc[i]) * ((Ly[i] + Ly[i+1])/2)
    if A1 > A2 and  Uy[i] < 0.0 :
        A += abs(A1) + abs(A2)
    elif A1 > A2 and ((Uy[i] + Uy[i+1] )/2)> 0:
        A += abs(A1) - abs(A2)
    elif A1 < A2 and A1 < 0.0 :
        A -= (abs(A2) - abs(A1))
    i += 1
return(A)
```

Where the Upper and Lower functions are just unpacking my data. So my main question is, does the np.trapz function account for the curve doubling back on itself as well as the negative area once they cross. And if not, Does mine?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/fZtW3hq for the image